# cant load windows 10 on ubuntu because I mount my hard drive on ubuntu

Tags: windows

my laptop can't find my hard disk to load up. I used a usb to install ubuntu. I tried to install but couldnt find the partitions of my disk. I change something while using ubuntu(trial) and now when I try to restart my pc it cant open..it says insert boot up something..can you help!!

Comment: What did you change?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubutbu cant find my hard disk and partitions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967519/ubutbu-cant-find-my-hard-disk-and-partitions)